# IP subnet verification in JSP

Tags: java, ip-address, netmask

I have the following JSP code, that protects my web page and displays it only to know IP's

```
String ip_h = request.getRemoteAddr();  
String host_h = request.getRemoteHost();  
String iplist[] = new String[1];  
iplist[0] = "127.0.0.1";  
iplist[1] = "10.217.106.248";  

int count = iplist.length;  
boolean flag = false;  
int zz = 0;  
//return;
System.out.println(host_h);  
while ( (flag==false) && ( zz < count) )  
{  
   if (ip_h.equals(iplist[zz]) || host_h.equals(iplist[zz]) )  
   {  
      flag = true;  
   }  
   zz++;  
}
```

However, I would to rather check for subnet ranges, i.e. all users belonging to 10.217.0.0/16 are allowed.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you need to also support ipv6 address ?

Answer (score 2):

IP addresses (at least, IPv4 addresses) are really intended to be represented as 32-bit integers. If you convert the IP address to an integer first, checking subnet ranges becomes a relatively simple matter of checking (in your example) whether the first 16 bits match the first 16 bits of the range.

Answer (score 2):

wouldn't you rather use the application server to lock down the ip range? In apache you can create an alias for a directory, put your code in the directory, then in the alias directive only allow certain ip or ranges:

Alias /mydir "/usr/local/mydir"

order deny,allow
    deny from all
    Allow from 10.217.106.248
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    allow from 10.217.106 #this is a range

this way you don't have to code this sort of "magic number"

I am sure you can do this type of thing in other web servers

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to use this IpRangeFilter class.  See class comment for explanation.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.commons.collections15.Predicate;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder;

/**
 * I am a filter used to determine if a given IP Address is covered by the IP range specified in 
 * the constructor.  I accept IP ranges in the form of full single IP addresses, e.g. 10.1.0.23
 * or network/netmask pairs in CIDR format e.g. 10.1.0.0/16
 */
public class IpRangeFilter implements Predicate<InetAddress> {

    private final long network;
    private final long netmask;

    private final String ipRange;

    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("((?:\\d|\\.)+)(?:/(\\d{1,2}))?");

    public IpRangeFilter(String ipRange) throws UnknownHostException {
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(ipRange);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String networkPart = matcher.group(1);
            String cidrPart = matcher.group(2);

            long netmask = 0;
            int cidr = cidrPart == null ? 32 : Integer.parseInt(cidrPart);
            for (int pos = 0; pos < 32; ++pos) {
                if (pos >= 32-cidr) {
                    netmask |= (1L << pos);
                }
            }

            this.network = netmask & toMask(InetAddress.getByName(networkPart));
            this.netmask = netmask;
            this.ipRange = ipRange;

        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid IP range: " + ipRange);
        }
    }

    public String getIpRange() {
        return ipRange;
    }

    public boolean evaluate(InetAddress address) {
        return isInRange(address);
    }

    public boolean isInRange(InetAddress address) {
        return network == (toMask(address) & netmask);
    }

    /**
     * Convert the bytes in the InetAddress into a bit mask stored as a long.
     * We could use int's here, but java represents those in as signed numbers, which can be a pain 
     * when debugging.
     * @see http://www.captain.at/howto-java-convert-binary-data.php
     */
    static long toMask(InetAddress address) {
        byte[] data = address.getAddress();
        long accum = 0;
        int idx = 3;
        for ( int shiftBy = 0; shiftBy < 32; shiftBy += 8 ) {
            accum |= ( (long)( data[idx] & 0xff ) ) << shiftBy;
            idx--;
        }
        return accum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Subnet` class from this [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4262187).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following piece of code, of course it assumes the input data are correct so it needs some beautifying (just in case)

```
public class IPUtil
{

    private static int[] split(String ip)
    {
        int[] result = new int[4];
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(ip, ".");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            result[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static boolean matches(String visitorIpString, String ipString, String maskString)
    {
        int[] vip = split(visitorIpString);
        int[] ip = split(ipString);
        int[] mask = split(maskString);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if ((vip[i] & mask[i]) != ip[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String ip = "192.168.12.0";
        String mask = "255.255.255.0";
        String visitorIP = "192.168.12.55";

        System.out.println(matches(visitorIP, ip, mask));
    }
}
```